# How many ring homomorphisms would there be from $F_{2}[x]$ to $F_{2}$?

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, ring-theory

How many ring homomorphisms would there be from $F_{2}[x]$ to $F_{2}$? I think that there is the trivial homomorphism, and a map that sends x to an element of $F_{2}$. So are there 2 ring homomorphisms?

Comment: the homomorphism is determined by the image of the polynomial $x$.

Comment: Beware that it varies between contexts and books whether the zero map into a nonzero ring counts as a ring homomorphism or not.

Comment: Should the homomorphism preserve the unity?

Comment: @HenningMakholm, so in this case it would be 2 or 3 correct?

Comment: @PhilKing: Yes, I agree.

Comment: I think that it does not count in my case, I think there are 2 then

Comment: @PhilKing I agree

Comment: @Peter they just substitution for 0 and 1 correct?

Comment: Yes, we can send $x$ either to $0$ or to $1$.